# Cordova add Android Platform error

Tags: android, cordova

I've installed android studio and latest sdk.
I've added sdk and tools path to PATH in system settings as following

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-studio\sdk\platform-tools;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-studio\sdk\tools;
```

I've verfieid the path of tools and its correct as well.. But still I'm get the error when I run the following command

cordova add platform android

This is the error im getting

```
e:\android\firstapp>cordova platform add android
[Error: The command `android` failed. Make sure you have the latest Android SDK
installed, and the `android` command (inside the tools/ folder) added to your pa
th. Output: 'android' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
]
```

Comment: what happens if you type `android` in a command window?

Comment: @Henry : its says: 'android' is not recognized as internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Comment: Then you need to fix that first. Something is wrong with the installation, maybe it is not in the PATH.

Comment: Okay that is very strange..! My path was already correct and installation was also fine.. I just restarted the CMD and everything went back to normal!